# BadRequest using Azure Service Management API to create VM

Tags: java, rest, azure, virtual-machine

i am writing a small java client that uses the Azure Service Management API to create a new VM Deployment on Azure.
i keep getting bad requests responses like these:

```
17/07/2012 18:26:37 com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST https://management.core.windows.net/my-subscription-id/services/hostedservices/myservice/deployments
1 > x-ms-version: 2012-03-01
1 > Content-Type: application/xml
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <Name>mynametest</Name>
  <DeploymentSlot>Staging</DeploymentSlot>
  <Label>mynamelabel</Label>
  <RoleList>
    <Role>
      <RoleName>mynamerolename</RoleName>
      <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
      <ConfigurationSets>
        <ConfigurationSet>
          <ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
          <HostName>myunamehost</HostName>
          <UserName>myname</UserName>
          <UserPassword>password</UserPassword>
        </ConfigurationSet>
      </ConfigurationSets>
      <OSVirtualHardDisk>
        <SourceImageName>CANONICAL__Canonical-Ubuntu-12-04-amd64-server-20120528.1.3-en-us-30GB.vhd</SourceImageName>
      </OSVirtualHardDisk>
    </Role>
  </RoleList>
</Deployment>

17/07/2012 18:26:38 com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 400
1 < x-ms-request-id: c622e270c5934cb493f76790b7d2c49d
1 < Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2012 15:27:26 GMT
1 < Content-Length: 275
1 < Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
1 < Server: 6.0.6002.18488 (rd_rdfe_stable.120710-1331) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
1 < 
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>No   target URI is specified for the image CANONICAL__Canonical-Ubuntu-12-04-amd64-server-20120528.1.3-en-us-30GB.vhd.</Message></Error>
```

it looks like the docs from azure are buggy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194

anyone has tried this before? i dont understand what does 'target URI' mean...
the image name is taken from the public gallery of images on azure.

any help, any help at all, will be highly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your xml have some bad configuration i.e. DeploymentSlot etc and I also believe the error is coming because you do not have all required settings in your XML. Following is the working one for Linux Gallery image:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Name>mydeploymentname</Name>
 <Label>mydeploymentlabel</Label>      
 <RoleList>
  <Role>
     <RoleName>mylinuxvm2012</RoleName>
     <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>      
     <ConfigurationSets>
        <ConfigurationSet> 
            <ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration<ConfigurationSetType>
            <HostName>host-name-for-the-vm</HostName>
            <UserName>new-user-name</UserName> 
            <UserPassword>password-for-the-new-user</UserPassword> 
            <DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>true|false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>           
            <SSH>
                <PublicKeys>
                   <PublicKey>
                       <FingerPrint>******add_here******</FingerPrint>
                       <Path>****SSH-public-key-storage-location**********</Path>     
                   </PublicKey>
                </PublicKeys>
                <KeyPairs>
                   <KeyPair>
                       <FingerPrint>************certificate-fingerprint*************</FinguerPrint>
                       <Path>*************SSH-public-key-storage-location*************</Path>
                   </KeyPair>
                </KeyPairs>
            </SSH>
        </ConfigurationSet> 
     <OSVirtualHardDisk>
        <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>    
        <DiskLabel>myosdisklabel</DiskLabel>
        <DiskName>myazurelinuxvm</DiskName>                    
        <MediaLink>https://_yourstoragename_.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/_your_VHD_NAME_.vhd</MediaLink>
        <SourceImageName>CANONICAL__Canonical-Ubuntu-12-04-amd64-server-20120528.1.3-en-us-30GB.vhd</SourceImageName>
     </OSVirtualHardDisk>      
     <RoleSize>_ExtraSmall|Small|Medium|Large|ExtraLarge_</RoleSize>      
  </Role>
</RoleList>
```

Comment: thanks!, the element i was missing is the <MediaLink> element. which is actually this target URI i was getting the error about. strange thing is that the azure docs say that this element is not required...

Comment: I am glad that your problem is resolved. Grateful if you mark it as answer.

Comment: In fact `MediaLink` is required when `SourceImageName` is there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx#OSVirtualHardDisk see documentation for `SourceImageName`.