# windows azure rest api - creating a virtual machine

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine

I am looking into using the Windows Azure REST API to create Virtual Machines in the Windows Azure environment. Looking into the Windows [Azure REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157186.aspx) I see that the URL to which the POST request  should be made is:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roles
```

My confusion here is about the need for `<cloudservice-name>` and `<deployment-name>`. In fact if I directly login to my Windows Azure subscription portal and go through the menu to create the Virtual Machine, I DON'T have to specify a cloudservice-name or deployment-name. All I do is choose an image (centos, ubuntu, windows etc.) for the VM, choose a flavor (xsmall, small, large etc.) for the VM and click on "Create" and the VM gets created in a few minutes.

Given I could create a VM this way, I am at a loss to understand why I have to pass a `<cloudservice-name>` and a `<deployment-name>` parameters in the REST API curl call and what values to pass to those parameters. In fact I don't have a deployment in my subscription, nor I intend to have one. All I want is simply create a virtual machine that I could use.

Is it possible for me to skip these parameters and still be able to create a Virtual machine in my Azure subscription? i.e. just only by passing the `<subscription-id>`?

Could someone who has used the Windows Azure REST API before or someone with expertise with Windows Azure throw some light on this and help clarify?

**Update Wed, 07/31/2013:** Thanks again for the feedback to my question. I would like to update that I was able to get to the point where I was able to finally create a Virtual Machine using a REST API call. But the strange thing is that creating the Virtual Machine successfully worked only once. Subsequently when I tried to create a VM with a different name, it gave an error like "Staging deployment is blocked". So just for the sake of sanity I went ahead and deleted the existing VM and and did some account cleanup. I tried the POST operation to create the VM again and now what is happening is that the POST response is coming back fine with a 202 Accepted message, but in spite of it I DON'T see a VM being created in my Azure account. I don't know where and how to even start troubleshooting this issue, given I am neither getting an error, nor the VM is getting created.

I am posting below the entire XML request body I am posting for creating the VM:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Staging</Name>
  <DeploymentSlot>Staging</DeploymentSlot>
  <Label>stk_curl_label_1</Label>
  <RoleList>
    <Role>
      <RoleName>stk_curl_role_1</RoleName>
      <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
      <ConfigurationSets>
        <ConfigurationSet>
          <ConfigurationSetType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
          <ComputerName>stkVm1</ComputerName>
          <AdminPassword>Password123</AdminPassword>
          <EnableAutomaticUpdates>false</EnableAutomaticUpdates>
        </ConfigurationSet>
      </ConfigurationSets>
      <OSVirtualHardDisk>
        <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
        <DiskLabel>Visual studio ultimate</DiskLabel>
        <DiskName>stk_disk_1</DiskName>
        <MediaLink>http://stk11.blob.core.windows.net/communityimages/visual_studio_ultimate.vhd</MediaLink>
        <SourceImageName>03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Visual-Studio-2013-Preview-Ultimate-12.0.20617.1</SourceImageName>
      </OSVirtualHardDisk>
      <RoleSize>ExtraSmall</RoleSize>
    </Role>
  </RoleList>
</Deployment>
```

And I am pasting below the tail of the response I am getting for the curl call:

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: management.core.windows.net
> Accept: */*
> x-ms-version: 2012-03-01
> Content-Type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 1236
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: 33.0.6198.68 (rd_rdfe_stable.130710-0833) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth
< x-ms-request-id: b2f3dd01319049a5a6728bbdbcde6c4a
< Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 17:26:54 GMT
* Connection #0 to host management.core.windows.net left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

As you could clearly see, it is a "202 Accepted" response. But as I mentioned earlier, in spite of this, when I check at my Azure account, I don't see a VM being created.

Would appreciate any expert insights/ideas on how to go about figuring out the root cause of why it isn't working as intended?

Comment: A 202 response is expected and normal for a Create Virtual Machine Deployment call. The operation is asynchronous. Once you receive the 202, you can poll the service for completion of the operation using the request id that was packed into the 202 response you received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is a little magic behind the scenes of the portal.  When you deploy a Virtual Machine it does indeed end up in a Cloud Service container.  This was recently changed to be more obvious in the portal as well, previously they were hiding this from you.  When people would delete the VM or add other VMs to the same group (previously called something like "attach to") the cloud service would show up in the portal.  People got confused on what this was and it just caused more questions than it was worth.

In the portal now you are prompted for a cloud service.  If you do the quick create when it asks for the DNS name (and shows the .cloudapp.net next to it) that's the Cloud Service name you are providing.  When you do the create via the Gallery it is even more obvious on step 3 where is asks to create a new Cloud Service or select one that already exists.

To do what you want via the REST API you'll need to create the cloud service ahead of time or as a call prior to the create for the VM.  Also, the link you provided is for adding a Cloud Service role, not creating a Virtual Machine.  For that REST API Call you'll want to use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx  It still requires the cloud service, but not the deployment name.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. That was some education on my side that you did. I wasn't aware of the "behind the scenes" stuff. After delving into more of the details, I was able to get to the point where I am able to submit a request for VM deployment. But I am now getting the following error:
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>No target URI is specified for the image 03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Visual-Studio-2013-Preview-Ultimate-12.0.20617.1.</Message></Error>

Comment: How do I find the target URI for the image? It doesn't seem to be returned as part of the list images call I make using the following curl call.

curl -E azure-cert.pem -H "x-ms-version: 2013-03-01" "https://management.core.windows.net/my-subscription-id/services/images"

Sorry, but this is the 1st time for me on stackoverflow. Do I use the comments section to discuss more or..? Please guide me.

Comment: It seems like I am missing the <MediaLink> tag as looking from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525988/badrequest-using-azure-service-management-api-to-create-vm. But the question is where from I get the value for the MediaLink. Sorry again if I am not supposed to post these in the comments. Please guide what is the right thing to do.

Comment: It would help if you posted the full payload that you are sending up minus any sensitive bits like the passwords, storage account names, etc.  Much like the person did in the other question.  Also, I think it would help if you updated the question itself with new information, as long as it is still the same question.  I think the issues you are running into qualify as the same question; however, if you get past that and suddenly ask how to install something or do this via the portal instead you should post a different question and rate the answer provided here as you see fit.

Comment: Check out the documentation for this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx.  If you supply a SourceImageName that points to an Azure specific image from the gallery you MUST supply a MediaLink URL. This is to a URI where a new VHD will be created which will be your OSDisk. You make that URL up that points to one of your storage accounts that belongs to the same subscription you are creating the VM in. In the example you pointed to they are pointing to a container named vhds and you just supply the name you wan the VHD to be. The operation will create the VHD.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different APIs, one for creating the deployment and a VM under a cloud service, the other for adding roles to the deployment you created earlier.

These are the 2 APIs

For VM deployment

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx
```

For Roles in a deployment

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157186.aspx
```

What you are using is the second one, you first need to create a VM deployment using the first API, then use the second one to add more roles in the same cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the add role returning me a 202 accepted but no VM was created.  After many hours trying to find out what was wrong, I found out that on the management portal they have these MANAGEMENT SERVICES -> operation logs where it shows you a log of all the API calls.

It was in here that my add role API call was telling me that it was a 404 bad request instead of a 202 accepted, and it showed me the specific error as well.

Management services -> operation logs are very useful when you are stuck with the API.

Comment: This helped tremendously. The XML body has a million parameters/dependencies, so seeing why exactly my VM wasn't being created was key to get it working.